# Android shuts down when unplugged

Tags: battery

I have an HTC One m8. It's running android 6.0.

If I attempt to boot up the phone it instantly shuts down when reaching the Google Logo.
If I plug it in to a power source (AC/usb), it lets me boot, but once I unplug the power source it instantly shuts down.

The battery is indicated to be close to 100%.

This really does sound like a hardware issue with the battery, **but I can still enter the bios** (Power + Vol Down) and leave it open for a few hours without it dying (probably longer, didn't test it for longer). It only shuts down when I attempt to either boot or enter recovery.

I've already re-flashed the OS to stock with:

```
fastboot oem rebootRUU
fastboot flash zip rom.zip
fastboot reboot
```

So my question is: **is this a hardware issue or software issue**?

Is it because entering the bios requires such a minimal amount of energy, my device will allow me to enter it even when it's on extremely low battery? Or is it because the software is somehow incorrectly detecting the battery level and shutting down?

Comment: Try replacing battery. It looks like battery issue to me

Comment: Ah I would if I could, htc one m8 = non-removable battery.

Comment: Ok. Try [resetting battery logic](http://forums.androidcentral.com/verizon-htc-one/394469-battery-charger-reset-procedure-htc-one-m7-m8.html). This may fix if it is a battery logic problem. HTC and some Nexus phones have this issue

Comment: Eventually entering the bios became impossible, so I know it's a hardware issue now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like your battery is broken or something. I suggest bringing it back to HTC and have them fix it for you. Please **don't** do it(replacing battery/open then phone case) by yourself as it will **void your phone warranty**.

*PS*: HTC will have their way to replace the battery for you, but I am not sure whether it will cost you some money or not.

Hope it helps =)

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps hardware issue. Android has a battery checker that shuts down your phone when out of energy. It does not always shut down right when your battery level reaches 0%; sometimes it shuts down when battery level is 5%, sometimes it doesn't even shut down after 1 hour of excessive use when battery level is 1%. So it is checking the battery not by battery level, but by something else, perhaps voltage.

Anyways, you should contact HTC for maintainence.